# Create Loopback and assign local addresses on Windows 8

Tags: networking, powershell, windows-8, loopback

I'm usually on OSX where I often add additional IP addresses to lo0 interface to simplify ssh tunnelling to various services on different machines to different local addresses:

```
# Tunnel mysql connections:
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.16.4.142
ssh -L172.16.4.142:3306:localhost:3306 my_mysql_server_dev
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.16.4.121
ssh -L172.16.4.121:3306:localhost:3306 my_mysql_server_test
# I can now locally connect to the remote mysql servers using
mysql -H 172.16.4.142
mysql -H 172.16.4.121
```

On Windows 8 how do I achieve this?
I understand I need to install the loopback adapter driver like so:
Got [Windows Driver Kit 8.1 Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42273) and ran the following commands:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Tools\x64\devcon.exe" -r install %WINDIR%\Inf\Netloop.inf *MSLOOP
powershell
$nic = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "Name='Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter'"
```

What now?  Can anyone help me with the next steps?  What I want to do is configure the interface with a bunch of local IPv4 addresses
The machine I'm running is a virtualbox image.

Once I have the local interface installed and a bunch of ip addresses assigned I'll configure the tunnelling in putty.

I tried following [this guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f6a4c454-6088-4022-8f0d-d73181247856/how-to-programatically-add-and-configure-loopback-adapter), but it seems outdated/not right for Windows 8.

Comment: You could probably solve this with `netsh`, although Microsoft doesn’t endorse it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my way will work but you can just try to use the 127.0.0.0/24 network for this. Windows will resolve all addresses within the 127.0.0.0/24 network to the local loopback device.

I think that this is easier then messing around with custom drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 supports the [New-NetIPAddress cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826150.aspx).

```
New-NetIPAddress –IPAddress 172.16.4.142 -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 172.16.4.1
New-NetIPAddress –IPAddress 172.16.4.121 -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 172.16.4.1
```

Comment: To which adapter do those commands assign to?

Comment: If you have multiple adapters you can specify using -InterfaceIndex.

Comment: These don't create new adapters though. You still need an existing adapter.

Comment: If I could create new adapters, do I need to create these IP addresses for these adapters. Don't the adapters have an IP address + subnet..etc already?

Comment: You're changing the topic of this question. Feel free to post a question of your own.